# delphixe2 "if-then" condition error

Tags: delphi, if-statement, compiler-errors, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I wrote the following code in delphi however it is not working as I want it to.

Is there a problem with this code?

function of this variant is returned:

```
   function DoRun(a:String;b:boolean):variant; 
   Begin   
       result:=a; 
   End;
```

this is using the above function is malfunctioning code:

```
 procedure TForm2.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);

    var   
        a,b,c:Integer;

    begin   

        a:=10;   
        b:=20;   
        c:=30;

        if (a=1) and (b=2) and (c=3) and DoRun('',true)='0' then

            showmessage('True');

    end;
```

RESULT : 'True' message see.

"if" line code end brackets "(DoRun('',true)='0')" worked by right running :

```
procedure TForm2.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject); 

var   
    a,b,c:Integer;

begin   
    a:=10;   
    b:=20;   
    c:=30;

    if (a=1) and (b=2) and (c=3) and (DoRun('',true)='0') then

        showmessage('True');

end;
```

Please help identify the problem and show me how I can make this code work as expected.

Comment: The first code when trying to display "true" message pops up that I can see. also no error code format.

Comment: Apart from anything else, you are creating problems for yourself by inconsistency.  Why would you write "(a=1)", with parentheses and then "DoRun('',true)='0'" without them, especially as part of the same boolean expression?

Comment: Avoid using `Variant`s unless you know that you really need them. I bet in this case would be enough to use `Boolean` as a result type.

Comment: @Martyn, you'd write some with parentheses and others without because the compiler rejected the original version of the code that lacked any parentheses at all. When you don't know what you're doing, you take shots in the dark until it compiles. If the compiler accepts it, it must be OK. ;)

Comment: not sure why you've assignment `=` operator and not comparison `==` operators in the conditional statement.

Comment: Bongs "==" operator not in delphi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All;

```
if ( (a=1) and (b=2) and (c=3) and DoRun('',true) ) = '0'
```

not the same

```
if ( DoRun('',true) and (a=1) and (b=2) and (c=3) ) = '0'
```

this is not running !! Run time error "Invalid Argument"!

Is not that the example you gave me the opposite? :):) You have a logic error! so , your answer has nothing to do with the subject of!

*Compiler interprets from left to right. compiler "DoRun()" error condition is caused by the algorithm can not be regarded as brackets. If "DoRun()" condition on the top of the conditions we get this error "RTE" that is why you will see to. Conditions at the beginning of "**brackets**" If you use as you will see that no compilation. In this case the compiler clearly not the final condition while allowing the brackets at the far right to the left does not permit.*

Yes, **the compiler incorrectly interprets!** but the compiler to interpret it that way!

Comment: interpreted according to the return type of the parameters sent! This code works in !! :(:( 

if (a=1) and (b=2) and (c=3) and DoRun('NO!WAR!',true)='0' then showmessage('True'); 

certainly compiler error. Show 'true' message see.

Comment: +1 again. yes! True. Try and write that they will see the problem.They're probably correct them.When you change a piece of code in circumstances where changing the compiler's reviews :( Unfortunately, delete it from your previous reviews have understanding! thnks.

Comment: Who are you talking to, who's you?

Comment: Providing information on the subject is talking to everyone. I think useful information. try to run is a programmer. And it shows.
Sertaç,People sharing ideas with each other can? @Lhristov than a useful sharing.

Comment: @Ersal - From the answer (?) you posted: *"You have a logic error! so , your answer has nothing to do with the subject of!"*. Who is you?

Comment: Sertaç,"You" is @Lhristov.

Answer (score 4):

First piece of code is definitely wrong. There your condition is

```
if ( (a=1) and (b=2) and (c=3) and DoRun('',true) ) = '0'
```

which equals to

```
if Variant(false) = Variant('0') then 
  ShowMessage('True');
```

and obviously for Variant type `false='0'`

The second piece of code is working as expected. The second comparison is OK, only boolean comparisons there, DoRun function is not executed and the result of comparison is `false`

Comment: +1 but I think it's rather equivalent with `if Variant(false) = '0' then`

Comment: *"DoRun function is not executed"* - depends on {$B}

Comment: @SertacAkyuz yes, but even if it is executed the result will remain `false`

Comment: No LHristov. First piece of code is definitely not wrong !! look carefully!! 

please,pay attention to the brackets! The first examples I gave my first example you gave is not the same!!

My example "IF" 

if (a=1) and (b=2) and (c=3) and DoRun('',true)='0' then

You example "IF"

if ( (a=1) and (b=2) and (c=3) and DoRun('',true) ) = '0' 

got it wrong!

Comment: Why do you think this code does not work well? @LHristov.
Compiling this code but it gives error.

"if DoRun('',true) and (a=1) and (b=2) and (c=3) ='0' then"
Result: "Ivalid Argument"
if a distinction as you say "run time error" would not!

Comment: is also why the following code does not compile?

"if DoRun('',true)='0' and (a=1) and (b=2) and (c=3) then"


This situation undermines your thesis _LHristov! 
must necessarily parentheses.
At the compiler and the end "variant" valuable function does the same comments !!!!

Comment: please pay attention! DoRun() function is return "variant" type! 
When converting different types of "bad variable type" returns.
"DoRun('',true)" string type returns results. thus,therefore "if (a=1) and (b=2) and (c=3) and DoRun('',true)='0' then" code "if ( (a=1) and (b=2) and (c=3) and DoRun('',true) ) = '0'" as is unthinkable! 

SO LOOKS LIKE A COMPILER ERROR.

Comment: @ErsalŞahin Your first example is exactly as mine in my answer because `and` has higher precedence than `=`. Look [here](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/expressions_xml.html). And all this _pseudo true_ result is from the variant type. This is not compiler but logical (human) error.

Comment: @LHristov But a situation like this! The compiler will first look at the brackets. Adding or eliminating brackets have not answered my question !! You're a self-produced solutions. Not the answer you gave me for my question, unfortunately. Because my question is "if (a=1) and (b=2) and (c=3) and DoRun('',true)='0'" your answer "if ( (a=1) and (b=2) and (c=3) and DoRun('',true) ) = '0' "! Both are different.

Comment: @LHristov Remove the outer parentheses in the example you gave, if you reach my question. Add a new comment found by yourself, but you're going. eg compiler was if he tries to add a parenthesis "if ( (a=1) and (b=2) and (c=3) and DoRun('',true)='0' )" would be. And looking at the example you gave me "if ( DoRun('',true) and (a=1) and (b=2) and (c=3) ) = '0'" Why does not "Invalid argument" is giving error? Boolean not perceive that because the string. According to the head of a compiler must work in such a way! Error here.